# Changing the default gateway address in Centos

Tags: networking, centos, linux-networking, centos6, ethernet

I have a a Centos PC with 2 IP addresses. One of them is because of a back to back connection with another PC, so both run on different subnets. The eth0 has the 192.xx.xx.xxx  address and eth2 has 172.xx.xx.xxx on this PC.

Since 192.xx.xx.xxx is a back to back connection it doesn't have internet capability, but 172.xx.xx.xxx does. The default is set to 192.xx.xx.xxx, so whenever I do a `yum` update or anything it goes through 192.xx.xx.xxx, it is not able to perform the update or I am not even able to ping www.google.com.

Is there a way I can set the default IP address for eth2 to, e.g., 172.xx.xx.xxx?

I have already tried going to the /etc/sysconfig/network and setting the gateway to 172.x.y.z, but it didnt work .

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the default gateway....you must know the router address off the 172 network to do this.

Open /etc/sysconfig/network file:

```
 vi /etc/sysconfig/network
```

Setup GATEWAY={Router-IP}, if router IP is 172.x.y.z, type:

```
 GATEWAY=172.x.y.z
```

Save and close the file. Here would be the completed file:

```
 NETWORKING=yes
 NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
 HOSTNAME=my.hostname.com
 GATEWAY=172.x.y.z
```

Comment: Tried your above suggestion already, didnt work for me. Thats why came to this forum for suggestions.